# Java Relationship between interfaces/abstract classes

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, interface

I am trying to build an algorithm that works in different ways depending on a *traversal strategy* and an *update strategy*. However, not every update Strategy works with every traversal strategy. Hence, I figured that an update strategy must only be instantiated with a corresponding traversal strategy. I wanted to force a constructor for that (see below). So that the subclasses would have to check if they support the strategy.

I am currently having an Interface

```
public interface TraversalStrategy {
...
}
```

And an (invalid) abstract class

```
public abstract class UpdateStrategy {
protected TraversalStrategy travStrategy;

public abstract UpdateStrategy(TraversalStrategy travStrategy);
}
```

What is the correct way to imply such a dependency? I could of course add an empty body to this constructor but that seemed wrong to me.

**Update:**
Inspired by the Answer of @Kayaman, I created a new class TestcaseGenerator that is used to construct a valid combination.

```
public TestcaseGenerator(TraversalStrategy travStrategy, UpdateStrategy updStrategy){
    if (updStrategy.supports(travStrategy)){
        this.travStrategy = travStrategy;
        this.updStrategy = updStrategy;
    }
}
```

[image: Current Class Diagram]

What I don't like about this yet is, that it would now be unnecessary to give the instance of TraversalStrategy to the UpdateStrategy in order to check if it is supported. I would rather only need the class name. Can you tell me how to achieve that? Experiments with `.getClass().getName()` seemed horrible. Currently I am doing:

```
public boolean supports(TraversalStrategy travStrategy){
   if(travStrategy instanceof UpstreamTraversalStrategy){ 
       return true; 
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Are all the possible update and traversal strategies (and which strategies are compatible with each other) known compile-time?

Comment: @PinkieSwirl Actually it's a syntax error.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl It does not have return type and is marked abstract.Neither a constructor nor a method

Comment: @KumarAbhinav you are right, I missed that there was no return type, thanks.

Comment: I'm confused. Did you delete your comment @PinkieSwirl? 

@MickMnemonic: Yes they are known at compile-time.

Comment: Then consider encapsulating the strategies as `enum`s.

Comment: @Koronis yes, to make things clear again: `public abstract UpdateStrategy(TraversalStrategy travStrategy);` is a syntax error. It is no constructor, since constructors can't be abstract and it is no abstract method, since a return type is missing.

Comment: Oh I tried to use enums a couple of times at other occassions and removed them again when I was done in the past. Do you mean the supported combinations? But I can't write something like
`public enum Combinations{
    One(UpdateStrategy1, TraversalStrategy1),
    Two(UpdateStrategy1, TraversalStrategy2),
   Three(UpdateStrategy1, TraversalStrategy3),...`

Comment: @PinkieSwirl: Alright yeah, that's why I wrote (invalid) :) . Thanks for adding the explanation for others!

Comment: No, I meant `public enum Updater implements UpdateStrategy` which would actually contain the implementations and list the supported traversal strategies.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I afraid I don't know enough about enums to understand how I would have to implement your solution without a bigger picture.

Comment: Are the different strategies always paired, i.e. do they have a 1-to-1 relationship (as in your "Upstream" example)? Or could `UpstreamUpdateStrategy` additionally support some other way of traversal than `UpstreamTraversalStrategy`?

Comment: @MickMnemonic No they aren't paired. Every `UpdateStrategy` can potentially support multiple `TraversalStrategy` s.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>One common way is to have the superclass constructor call an abstract method such as `isSupported(TraversalStrategy t);` and fail if it's not true.</strike>

The subclasses would then implement the method accordingly by using `instanceof` or any other way to determine if the strategy is a supported one.

One approach would be to create a third class with a `Builder` pattern approach. Instead of providing `TraversalStrategy` as a parameter to `UpdateStrategy`, they would both be included in the third object (and they could be checked at `build()` to prevent incompatible strategies).

You could then have general functionality in the third class, with the strategy classes becoming lighter.

Comment: I was just about to answer in the same way, but then I remembered Joshua Bloch saying that it's always wrong to call an overridable method from a constructor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a valid idea. I'm gonna experiment and give feedback tomorrow :) .

Answer (score 1):

Even an abstract class must have a valid constructor. Even through it is not possible to create an instance of an abstract class, a non abstract subclass always calls the constructor of the super class first. Therefore your constructor on the abstract class needs a body to initialize the `TraversalStrategy`.

Comment: That's how I currently have it implemented. But I feel this makes people think that there is already some kind of checking in the super(TraversalStrategy travStrategy) constructor. And that's not true. I want to make sure that future programmers understand what they have to do with the constructor. Or find a better solution. :)

Comment: So put it down as a contract in the JavaDoc of the constructor. This will document the API which will be most relevant for any future developer using that abstract class.